# Conditional Statements - If Then vs. Select Case

Tags: vb.net

I'm a bit new to programming, and based on the few sources I've read both on the web and the books I'm learning to teach myself they are able to define what IF THEN and SELECT CASE conditional statements are, but have failed to give a comparison as to why I would use one over the other and what best practices decide this.

If I'm understanding these conditional statements correctly, then both are based on a set of conditions with an outcome based around meeting these conditions, and if no conditions are met then an alternative outcome can be defined.

I'm having trouble in understanding when I would use an IF THEN statement, and when I'd use a SELECT CASE statement, and what best practices are used to define this decision.

Any insight on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should accept an answer if you like it. If you don't like any answers, follow-up with clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, you can do the same exact thing with both. If you ever find yourself writing a ton of if statements: 
if
else if
else if 
else if 
else if 
etc. . . 

Then you would want to write a switch case block. It would make the code a little more readable. Technically either one would make the code work, but it is conventional to use a switch case block after about 4 or so if statements.

Answer (score 3):

It's quite simple:

- IF THEN is used for generic **conditions** (boolean conditions)
- SELECT CASE is used when you want to do different things according to the value of an **expression** (which resolve to values) and it's useful when you have multiple choices for different values because the statement is more readable and can possibly be compiled in a more efficient way

When you see that you are using more than 3-4 if/else statements in a chain for the same expression then using a case instruction is generally a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

The real differences between `SELECT...CASE` and `If/Then/Else` conditionals are the ability to use multiple disparate conditions in If/Then/Else and the corresponding need to re-evaluate any variable values in the contitional for each If/ElseIf condition. Since each CASE conditional can only make one single evaulation, it is optimized by the compiler to only make one single evaulation for the conditional variable. Each time a variable needs to be evaluated, that means a trip to a memory location. In modern systems, this happens extremely fast but if you're optimizing for millions of transactions each trip down memory lane counts. Hope this makes sense.